# 'this webpage has a redirect loop' when I tried login

Tags: jsf, shiro

I tried migrate project JSF from netbeans(ANT) to IntellijIDEA(maven) and Ihave problems.
In Web.xml I have filter:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>auth</filter-name>
        <filter-class>myPackeg.SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
```

And Filter class:

```
public class SessionTimeoutFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if (null == req.getSession(false) && !req.getRequestURL().toString().contains("/login.xhtml")) {
            if (isAjax(req)) {
                resp.getWriter().print(xmlPartialRedirectToPage(req, "/login.xhtml"));
                resp.flushBuffer();
            } else {
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
            }
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    private boolean isAjax(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
    }
```

When app start I have error in browser:

```
this webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

And in console I have this error:

```
13-Jan-2016 15:15:27.215 SEVERE [http-nio-8089-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/NurCRM] threw exception [/login.xhtml @9,113 listener="#{loginBean.authorizedUserControl}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null] with root cause
 javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /login.xhtml @9,113 listener="#{loginBean.authorizedUserControl}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2563)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2114)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:287)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at kg.nurtelecom.crm.filter.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This my Login.xhtml fragment:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent" listener="#{loginBean.authorizedUserControl}"/>
        </f:metadata>
        ...
```

also  I use Shiro auth:

```
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
...
[urls]
/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/images/** = anon
/error/ = anon
/login.xhtml = authc
/logout = logout
/** = authc
```

Comment: I did it in the first place. doFilter method calls itself permanently

Comment: you know what I first checked all the debugger? I put a lot of breakpoints and stepping all passed. And only then asked. I have found out that the reason is that there is a conflict with Shiro

Comment: How do you call login in the browser is it : /login.html or /login.xhtml ?

Comment: naturally login.xhtml

Comment: the error message seems to be clear. loginBean is not defined (you probably have to declare it), JSF tries to redirect to an error page and the filter loops

Comment: So basically the flow is that: 1) login.xhtml has an error 2) the server will trigger a redirect to the error page 3) the error page incorrectly trips a redirect to the login page due to not being logged in - 1) login.xhtml has error, 2) etc. The root of the problem is then how to get the redirect to login to not happen on error.

Comment: How can you require your login page to be accessible **only** when authenticated???